# what's the best guidance on replacing your own answer?

Tags: discussion

I answered a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687697/html5-video-closed-captioning-turn-off-or-on-methods), for reference) and because I wasn't happy with it went and did some more research and came up with a better way to solve the problem.

I edited my original answer to add the new solution (leaving the old kludge in case the concept had any value), but - is this the best way to do that?

Should I have:

- deleted the old, sub-optimal (for this case) solution?
- created a new answer?
- updated the answer and nuked the orginal solution because it's a red-herring?

I had a search in help before updating my answer but couldn't find anything that addressed this (though I am the first to admit I didn't spend that much time searching)

Answer (score 3):

I would choose:

> update the answer and nuke the original solution because it's a red-herring

There's no reason to keep the bad answer because, well, it's a bad answer. Only keep the clearer answer around so that good, pertinent knowledge is preserved.